# PowerBI, Filter, Search, and Create a new table from the result, DAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Please read patiently as I explain my current challenge. 
I am currently working with PowerBI, and I would like some help with a current task, I think might involve DAX, but I am not so sure.

BackgroundInfo:
I have a table called "Main_File". This table contains 7 columns, but I am only interested in the contents of just 3 columns which are called: "ShortDescription", "LongDescription", and "ProblemSolution".
The contents of this columns are various texts.

Challenge:
I want to filter these 3 columns based on some specific keywords. That is, How can I search through every rows in these columns for the occurence of one or more keywords, and filter out the rows that have these keyword(s)

Example:
Let the contents of one row in the table ("Main_File") have the following contents in the 3 columns I am interested in:

1. ShortDescription = "Alert of an unknown computer for the power point app"
2. LongDescription = "User received an alert on his Power Point Application"
3. ProblemSolution = "Alert disabled and the application works perfectly"

My keywords: "PowerPoint", "power point",  "Power-Point"

What I have done:

- I have used "Conditional Columns, but the result were not optimal.

=========================================
Your kind assistance and prompt response would really help an intern alot.

Comment: You can use Query Editor to accomplish this task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-query-overview

Comment: Thank Rado. But, I have used it before. it's from the query editor, you create conditional columns or compare table columns and filter based on the columns.